# displaying non-english characters as ????? in Internet explorer

Tags: php, encoding

I'm posting values of 3 text fields,(English, Chinese and Arabic) to a php page using **AJAX**.

When I try to echo the values in Internet Explorer, I get "????"

The same code works fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

I've already defined the UTF-8 Character set.

Here's my .JS file

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","save_banner.php?banner1="+b1+"&banner2="+b2+"&banner3="+b3 , true);
```

.PHP file

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');


echo $_GET['banner1'];
echo $_GET['banner2'];
echo $_GET['banner3'];
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: `.js file` - so this text is 'included' into page? Check charset of main page (container) too.

Comment: so will be any answer from you? What is charset of main page?

Answer (score 2):

Hi
Try without the metatag charset="UTF-8" but make sure your file is saved with UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing with IE8? I had this weird issue with IE8 where it refused to display non-english character sets

Add this to the `<head>` and see if it helps

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

It basically forces IE8 to render like IE7 ala 'quirks mode'. Annoying, but it solved the issue for me at least.

Comment: Yes, it was a hack at best - but it got me out of the hole I was stuck in. Would be good to know a proper solution with the root cause

Comment: my all pages are saved with utf-8 encoding, i have tried <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />, but its not working. :(
i am using the IE9

Comment: hi guys, i am still stuck with this problem.

Comment: @asif hameed: you might want to answer OZ_

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution :)

If you try to post the data using ajax than you have to encode the url using the `encodeURIComponent()` or `escape()` functions. It works for me.